# NodeJs EHOSTUNREACH in Express

Tags: node.js, api, express, ubuntu

I am facing problem on server while calling external API on HTTPS. I am checking with HTTPS.  On Local its working fine without any issue

Here is my error

> Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 54.147.133.143:443
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
> errno: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
> code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '54.147.133.143',
> port: 443
> }

if i hit the curl request on server directly and its working fine.

> curl -H "Authorization: Bearer mytoken"
> https://api.example.com/v3/a/accountid/companies.json

Any idea what could be the issue

Comment: did you try sending it with `http` ?

Comment: yes, on http i am getting only HTTPS are allowed

Comment: Have you tried to send the request through ngrok ?

Comment: no. but why ngrok?

Comment: where is your request code ?